# Contiki: Error if ELF File contains calculation with several unsinged int

Tags: file, elf, linear-regression, contiki

I encountered some problems while working with the contiki ELF-loader and hope that someone would be so kind to provide me more insight or some hints to solve these problems. In the following I try to keep the problem description short.

**My aim is to:**

- Execute an ELF file on a T-Mote-Sky.
- This ELF file contains a contiki process with a computation 
  (linear regression of data samples over time).
- Using "cooja" for simulation

**Code specific information:**

- ELF file size about 2000 bytes
- quite large computation of several unsigned-int-16 numbers:

---

```
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    sum_x += records[i].index;
    sum_y += records[i].energy;
    sum_xx += ((uint16_t) records[i].index) * ((uint16_t) records[i].index);
    sum_xy += ((uint16_t) records[i].index) * ((uint16_t) records[i].energy);
    }
    slope = ((size * sum_xy) - (sum_x * sum_y)) / ((size * sum_xx) - (sum_x * sum_x));
```

---

- "records" is initialised and defined in the main process, 
  which calls the elfloader, and is accessed via the extern definition
- it works if I use constants for the computation

**Problems:**

- if I try to use multiplication with "*" it leads to 
  the error message: `Symbol not found: __MPY`
- if I try to use division with "/" it leads to a similar 
  error message

  - so my workaround is that the multiplications and 
    divisions are based upon additions, and it works (in most cases)
- Still, I get the error: "Segment not found:" as soon as 
  I try to calculate the slope.

  - I deduce its an issue with the memory size 
    or trying to get data from the main process via extern,
    because calculating the slope works if I use constants only.

Many thanks in advance for your help and best regards,

Ca Way Le

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (symbol not found) when trying to load an elf file containing calculations with floats, so I used a workaround in case anyone is interested

- Compile the elf file

  ```
  make elfname.ce SMALL=0
  ```
- Open the elf file with a hex viewer and locate the part where symbols are stored. It is near the end of file.
- Let's assume that the symbols stored there are: `timer_set __addsf3 __subsf3, printf puts autostart_processes`. (The name of the process to be loaded is also among these values, but ignore it)
- Create a new file *mysymbols.c* in the project directory with the following contents

  ```
  #include "loader/symbols.h"

  extern int __addsf3();
  extern int __subsf3();
  extern int etimer_set();
  int printf(const char *, ...);
  extern int puts();

  const int symbols_nelts = 7;
  const struct symbols symbols[7] = {
  { "__addsf3", (void *)&__addsf3 },
  { "__subsf3", (void *)&__subsf3 },
  { "autostart_processes", (void *)&autostart_processes },
  { "etimer_set", (void *)&etimer_set },
  { "printf", (void *)&printf },
  { "puts", (void *)&puts },
  { (const char *)0, (void *)0} };
  ```

  (notice that the symbols must be sorted)
- Add the following code in the makefile

  ```
  ifdef CORE
  .PHONY: symbols.c symbols.h
  symbols.c:
       $(NM) $(CORE) | awk -f $(CONTIKI)/tools/mknmlist > symbols.c
  else
       symbols.c symbols.h:
       cp mysymbols.c symbols.c
       cp ${CONTIKI}/tools/empty-symbols.h symbols.h
  endif
  ```
- Now compile the file which contains the main process

  ```
  make TARGET=sky clean CLEAN=symbols.?
  make your-file.sky TARGET=sky SMALL=0
  ```
- Load the elf file to the mote running the main process and see what happens when the elfloader loads the elf

This worked for me for the case of *symbol not found* error.