# Symbol not found __udivsi3

Tags: dynamic-linking, msp430, contiki

I compiled my one of the Contiki application (power-cons.c: which evaluate the power consumption of TelosB mote) as a Contiki executable (power-cons.ce). The Contiki executable is then uploaded to the Sky platform via serial and is stored in the file system Then the executable is loaded via the shell command "exec".

But when running the command exec the following error is displayed...

> Symbol not found __udivsi3

How can I resolve this symbol?

Comment: Why are you using dynamic linking?

Comment: Quite similar problem with [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26240516/contiki-error-if-elf-file-contains-calculation-with-several-unsinged-int/27908999#27908999).
Check if the answer there helps.

Comment: @CL when I dynamically link (elf loader) the .ce module without using "exec" command, the same error symbol not found is displayed

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that all functions used by your `.ce` must already be on your Sky node (I'll call it base-system). All symbols provided by your base-system can be listed by running `nm base-system.sky`. Symbols needed by your `.ce` are the ones marked with `U` when running `nm power-cons.ce`. To solve your problem you have the following options:

- Do not use `__udivsi3` is your `.ce`. It used for dividing two `unsigned int` ([manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Integer-library-routines.html#index-g_t_005f_005fudivsi3-37)). You can for example use a `signed int`.
- Use `__udivsi3` in your base-system.
- Add
  `void__udivsi3(void);
  void (*additional_symbol1)(void) = &void__udivsi3;`
  to one of your files. This will cost you two bytes though.
- Use the solution presented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26240516/contiki-error-if-elf-file-contains-calculation-with-several-unsinged-int/27908999#27908999) as suggested by @finmor
- Tell the linker to include the function to your base-system. This is a bit tricky as a wasn't able to find a convenient way to do so. I did some experiments and it is not as simple as I hoped.
- You can add `__udivsi3` to your `.ce`. I'm not sure about the best or easiest way of doing this. Probably you want to extract the `.o` containing `__udivsi3` from the `.a`. This needs some searching. For `__udivsi3` this comes with the gcc (not the libc). Then you can merge it with your `power-cons.ce` using `ld -r` ([starting point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980102/combine-two-gcc-compiled-o-object-files-into-a-third-o-file)). There are other ways of ding this, too, but I'd have to do some research, as I'm currently not actively working on this topic.

Comment: Added " LDFLAGS +=-Wl,--undefined=__udivsi3 " in "makefile.msp430". But its not working

Comment: void__udivsi3(void); void (*additional_symbol1)(void) = &void__udivsi3; This is also not working

Comment: @sijukoshy I actually tested that. You do have to add that to your base system, not the module.

Comment: when I use "nm base system.sky" I could see "0000c914  T  __udivsi3 " and running "nm power-cons.ce" it list "  U  __udivsi3 ". The same error symbol not found: __udivsi3 is still existing.

Comment: Does it show up in your symbols.c, which is crated at build-time of your base-system?

Comment: symbols.c does not contain the symbol __udivsi3

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to link with libm.

Try adding `-lm` to your linker command line.
Also make sure libm is available on your target.

Comment: I already added TARGET_LIBFILES += -lm in makefile..But the same error is displayed